# DeltaSpike interface configuration not injectable

Tags: java, weld, deltaspike

I'm following the [DeltaSpike documentation](https://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/configuration.html#_interface_based_configuration) to create an injectable interface that binds configuration properties.

```java
@Configuration(prefix = "application.")
public interface AppConfig {

    @ConfigProperty(name = "name", evaluateVariables = false)
    String getApplicationName();
}
```

I've tried using it both via [`BeanProvider#getContextualReference`](https://deltaspike.apache.org/javadoc/1.9.3/org/apache/deltaspike/core/api/provider/BeanProvider.html#getContextualReference-javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager-java.lang.Class-boolean-java.lang.annotation.Annotation...-) and with `@Inject`.

```java
@Inject
public Framework(final AppContext context, final BeanManager beanManager, AppConfig app) {
    this.appContext = context;
    this.beanManager = beanManager;
    logger.info("Initialization application with name {}.", app.getApplicationName());
}
```

```java
Exception in thread "main" org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type AppConfig with qualifiers @Default
```

I also receive the warning:
`Unsatisfied dependency: no bean matches the injection point`

I've tried fiddling with the `beans.xml` file and dependencies in `build.gradle` but to no avail, and I'm unsure what I'm doing wrong compared to the documentation.

Could someone try to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't with DeltaSpike, but rather with Weld, the CDI implementation the project depends on.

The issue is caused from Gradle building the `main` and `resource` separately, so first the resource output needs to be modified to put them together. This sets the resource output to the classes directory.

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        output.resourcesDir = output.classesDirs.singleFile
    }

    test {
        output.resourcesDir = output.classesDirs.singleFile
    }
}
```

Then, run the application with Gradle instead of the IDE, to do this, add and configure the `application` plugin. This will create a Gradle task called `run`.

```
plugins {
    id "application"
    id "java"
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.0.9.RELEASE"
}

application {
    mainClassName = "org.example.app.Main"
}
```

If one is using DeltaSpike annotations, they may need to modify `beans.xml` to find `all` rather than `annotated`.

More information:
https://discuss.gradle.org/t/application-plugin-run-task-should-first-consolidate-classes-and-resources-folder-or-depend-on-installapp-or-stuff-like-weld-se-wont-work/1248

Repository containing a minimal DeltaSpike / Weld / Gradle project:
https://gitlab.com/SethFalco/mini-deltaspike